# error in java "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JDispLoad63 in java.library.path"

Tags: java

I have a .jar

when I execute , they give me this error:

```
[15:50:38 ~/Contrats]$java -jar impresionContrs.jar
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JDispLoad63 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1744)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1026)
at com.clarify.cbo.KJniDisp.<clinit>(KJniDisp.java:1003)
at com.clarify.cbo.Application.<init>(Application.java:81)
at es.impresionContrats.impresionContrats.ProcAsincrons_1(impresionContrats.java:174)
at es.impresionContrats.impresionContrats.main(impresionContrats.java:114)
```

can you help me to  fix this error?

Comment: (Hint: Provide code). Not sure if it is about the code though. Looks like something titled JDispLoad63 is not niculded in the path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not charging the libraries in the classpath.